# LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE cannot find path

Tags: mysql, database, path, workbench

Im using MySQL Workbench and tried using load data local infile. I have my table "mysample" with three columns: id, names, age.

Im trying to load a csv file and import it inside my table. id is auto_increment so I will insert the datas to names and age.  This is my query:

```
load data local infile 'C:\Users\vissia18\Desktop\sample.csv' into table mysample fields terminated by ','
enclosed by '"'
lines terminated by '\n'
(names, age)
```

But the problem is I'm having an error like this:

```
Error Code: 2. File 'C:\Users\vissia18\Desktop\sample.csv' not found
```

Why is that? How should I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

According to [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html):

> The file name must be given as a literal string. On Windows, specify backslashes in path names as forward slashes or doubled backslashes.